# Toolbar title disappears after launching fragment using NavGraph

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I have setup the toolbar title in NavGraph with

```
`private void setUpNavigationToolbar(){
        
final NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container_fragment;        
NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();

AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration =
          new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(
                toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    }`
```

and toolbar title is set using
`android:label="Sample title"` inside the Nav graph
When the fragment is launched the title appears and disappear in a moment.

I am looking for a solution for the toolbar title persists even after launching the fragment

Comment: Are you setting title directly to the toolbar in xml layout ? May be there is some thing in your configuration that sets toolbar title depends on what fragment you are showing and may be you should set title to each your fragment in your nav graph?

Comment: Why are you calling `setupWithNavController` on your toolbar if you only want a static title?

Comment: I want the toolbar to be updated based on the android:label"" inside the nav graph